# How to run send and receive traffic over 2 instances of dpdk-testpmd running on the same host?

Tags: dpdk

Note: I'm new to network and dpdk, so there might be some misunderstanding in fundamental concepts...

I want to run 2 instances of `dpdk-testpmd` on the same host to send and receive traffic over separate NIC.

Configuration:

NIC:

- PMD: MLX5
- version: 5.0-1.0.0.0
- firmware-version: 16.26.1040 (MT_0000000011)
- NUMA-Socket: same
- PCIe: 0000:3b:00.0, 0000:3b:00.1

**Update**

- DPDK Version: 20.11.1
- Hugepage Total: 32768
- Hugepage Free: 32768

TESTPMD Logs:

```
Logical Core 12 (socket 0) forwards packets on 6 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00
```

Questions:

1. How to set the MAC address of instance 2's port in instance 1?
2. What's the meaning of RX P=0/Q=0?
3. Is the NIC will receive packets from it's RXQ 0(a ring buffer in memory?)
4. Is the NIC will put packets(just got from RXQ) to it's TXQ 0?
5. What will happen next?
6. Where is the packet's destination?
7. How to set/check it?

Hope for your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please update the following information `1) DPDK version, 2 DPDK NIC used, 3) grep Huge /proc/meminfo (assuming it is linux), 4) NIC firmware in use`. With respect to your question it is misleading, please correct if your question is `how to run 2 instance of testpmd or How to set the MAC address of instance 2's port in instance `. Also explain `Some missed classroom knowledge?`

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thank you for reply. I've updated information you demand. And my question is : I know how to RUN 2 testpmd instance, but I don't know how to make them connected, and I think tell them the MAC address of each other is a key step.Hope for your help.

Comment: based on your latest comment, editing your question to reflect `I know how to RUN 2 testpmd instance, but I don't know how to make them connected, and I think tell them the MAC address of each other is a key step`. Also please note you have not mentioned whether you are using `PF or VF`. Also not shared the actual cmdline used.

Comment: I humbly request to please focus on 1 question, multiple sub questions in the same question is not a good practice. But since you are new to the forum I will try my best to answer your queries below

Comment: please note requesting information is not `demanding` as you highlighted in the comments. It is better to understand and help you with the answer. There is not demand from me to provide clarification for vague questions. Only humble request to help me to help you. Thanks for your kind co-operation.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks for your help! Even there is no cable connection between the 2 NICs so I can't make it today, but I believe your answer is exactly correct.I'm sorry for the word **demand** , I'm not a native speaker and don't realize the word is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: I highly recommend reading about dpdk testpmd as it covered all your questions in detail. As per the StackOverflow guideline multiple sub-questions make answering difficult. Please use well-formatted and formed question for better reach and answers.**

@Alexcured since you have mentioned *you know how to run 2 separate instances of `dpdk-testpmd`*. I will only recommend heavily reading up on [dpdk-testpmd URL](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/index.html) which has answers to most of your questions too.

The assumption is made, both the PCIe NIC are working properly and interconnect between 2 are tested with either arping or ping (Kernel Driver). After binding both PCIe devices to DPDK supported drivers, one should use options for DPDK 20.11.1 such as

- use file-prefix option as unique names
- set socket-memory to fetch memory from the desired NUMA-SOCKET
- set socket-limit to prevent ballooning of huge page mmap
- use w|b option to whitelist|blacklist PCIe devices (0000:3b:00.0 and 0000:3b:00.1)
- Since it is separate physical devices ensure there physical cable connection between 2 PCIe ports.

[Q.1] How to set the MAC address of instance 2's port in instance 1?

```
[A.1] in DPDK instance-1 & instance 2, execute `show port 0 mac` to show current port MAC address. Note down the MAC address correctly. To set the MAC address of peer use command `set eth-peer (port_id) (peer_addr)`.
In non interactive mode this can be done from cmdline too.
```

[Q.2] What's the meaning of RX P=0/Q=0?

```
[A.2] P stands for `port`, and Q stands for `queue`. So P=0/Q=0 means `port 0/queue 0`
```

[Q.3] Is the NIC will receive packets from it's RXQ 0(a ring buffer in memory?)

```
[A.3] NIC can receive from port 0 - rxq -0; provided there is no offload|RSS|Rules set (since you have not shared the cmdline I will assume there is none). 
NIC HW RQ is mmaped to reflect HEAD-TAIL pointer to allow PMD to trigger DMA copy to mempool (huge page backed area). This is different from DPDK lib_rte_ring buffer area
```

[Q.4] Is the NIC will put packets(just got from RXQ) to it's TXQ 0?

```
[A.4] if the option `start tx-first` is not used, as per the current understanding there will not be any packets TX from the NIC (for Intel FVL LLDP packets will be send from NIC HW unless disabled).
The default configuration in looped mode, and with 1 DPDK port RX of the Port will be always sent out as TX.
```

[Q.5] What will happen next?

```
[A.5] Packet will be send out with modified eth-peer mac address
```

[Q.6] Where is the packet's destination?

```
[A.6] Ethernet Packet has the format of first 6 bytes as destination MAC address. With `set peer-address` done the MAC address as the destination will be set as value set.
```

[Q.7] How to set/check it?

```
[A.7] use option `set verbose 2`. This will show the RX packet details received from the port
```